# Facebook Group Plugin not responsive

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-group

I was wondering if anyone knew how to make the Facebook GROUP Plugin responsive and resize it to the width of the parent div?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/group-plugin

Above is the SDK for the group plugin.

Everytime I use the SDK, I can't get the plugin to resize as the parent div changes, no matter what I try.

If anyone can help, that would be great!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried creating a new class setting the width of the class to 100%, setting the width of it to auto, also tried adding just the iframe that the plugin generates and setting the width of that to 100%.
Doing the latter does modify the width of the iframe but cuts off the width of the iframe as it gets smaller.

Comment: Yea that will not work. You have to set the data-width attribute before you render the component.

Comment: I've already done that, but its not responsive.  I figured I'd leave that out from what I've done because that's typically a given.

Comment: You have to do that before you render the component. When you init the FB SDK it will render the component. You have to make sure to change it before it render it

Comment: Don’t expect to much in terms of “responsiveness” from the Facebook social plugins. At best they are usually able to adapt to the current dimensions when they are initialized … but don’t expect them to play nice when you change screen size or device orientation.

Comment: Facebook does not provide any help in terms of making the plugins responsive. The data-width attribute is the persisted width through all screen sizes. I found some success by isolating .fb-group .fb_iframe_widget span {} css tag that is initialized when the script runs.